# Delegate, NSOrderedSet and a Mutable Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays

QUESTION:

I have a TableViewCell that draws from a Mutable Array that has Data from an NSOrderedSet. The NSOrderedSet contains all the info I need, but the Array, and subsequently the TableViewCell do not have any data in them at runtime.

Can I use delegate methods to fix this? What else could I be missing, or why the Array doesn't contain data? If so, how/what?

HERE IS THE CODE:

Currently I have a a `prepareForSegue` that I thought set it all up, but like I said its not displaying anything.

Here is the code I use in `prepareForSegue` that I thought would work

```
cannedResponsesViewController.cannedResponses   = company.cannedResponses;
cannedResponsesViewController.delegate          = self;
```

The view that contains the TableViewCell is the `cannedResponsesViewController` and `cannedResponses` is the `NSOrderedSet`  that stores the data I want.

Inside the `cannedResponsesViewController` I call this to get the `NSMutableArray` data from the `cannedResponses` OrderedSet:

```
self.searchResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.cannedResponses array]];
```

Comment: Did you implement the UITableView datasource methods?

You need to implement:

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: Yes I have implemented those methods

Comment: Did you set the tableview delegate to your view controller?

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([self isSelectionMode]) {
        FHCannedResponse *cannedResponse = _searchResults[indexPath.row];
        [_delegate cannedResponsesViewController:self didSelectCannedResponse:cannedResponse];

Comment: I am assuming that cannedResponsesViewController has a UITableView and this is where you are trying to display your data. This view needs to be set as the delegate to the UITableView and this is where you implement the UITableView datasource methods.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{   self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

Comment: in viewDidLoad of cannedResponsesViewController I believe I set the tableView and its datasource to the view